# The letter 'i' not visible properly

Tags: sencha-touch

I am using sencha touch for one of my projects and surprisingly the letter 'i' does not appear properly(it looks like a small 'l' instead) Please check the picture that I have posted.

The font and the case of the text cannot be changed because that is the requirement of the client. I am not posting any code because there is no issue in the functionality but just the display of this one particular letter. I am frustrated with this but I am sure that someone out there can figure this out. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. When I change the resolution then the letter appears correctly

[image]

This is the css on the parent panel:

```
*, ::after, ::before {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-user-drag:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.x-stretched.x-container > .x-inner, .x-stretched.x-container > .x-body, .x-stretched.x-container > .x-body > .x-inner {
  -webkit-box-flex:1;
  -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
  display:-webkit-box;
  flex:1 0 auto;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:0;
}

.x-inner, .x-body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.generalInfoMainName {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: opensans-bold;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is the HTML for the div that holds the text "AMA Building":

```
<div class="x-inner x-panel-inner" id="ext-element-692">
<div class="x-innerhtml" id="ext-element-693">
<span style="color: white;">AMA Building</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is going to be an HTML/CSS issue, not sencha touch. Can you post HTML, CSS snippets and details of which browser you're seeing this in. Have you tried it on device?

Comment: @shepsii It happens everywhere. IE, Chrome and Mobile as well. I will post the jsfiddle link soon..